# Given $P(X\perp Y\;|\;Z)$ and $P(X\perp Y\;|\;W)$, prove or disprove that $P(X\perp Y\;|\;Z, W)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given $P(X\perp Y\;|\;Z)$ and $P(X\perp Y\;|\;W)$, prove or disprove that $P(X\perp Y\;|\;Z, W)$

I'm pretty sure this isn't true, as I haven't been able to prove it using Bayes' Theorem and messing around with marginal distributions.  Nevertheless I haven't been able to find a directed graphical model which acts as a counter example, can anyone show me an example (doesn't have to be a graphical model) of where this doesn't hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition is that it is possible that the pair $(Y,Z)$ or $(Y,W)$
cannot determine $X$; but $(Y,Z,W)$ together can determine $X$.
The following counter example is constructed from this intuition.

Suppose $X,Y,Z,W$ are four binary discrete random variables that
could take values from $\{1,-1\}$. Assume $P(Y=1)=P(Z=1)=P(W=1)=1/2$.
Assume $Y,Z,W$ are mutually indepedent, and 
$$
X=Y\times Z\times W.
$$
Then one can verify that $X\perp Y\vert Z$ and $X\perp Y\vert W$.
But
$$
P(X\vert Y,Z,W)\neq P(X\vert Z,W),
$$
because $X$ will be completely determined by $Y,Z,W$. For instance,
$P(X=1\vert Y=1,Z=1,W=1)=1$ but $P(X=1\vert Z=1,W=1)=1/2$.